# Erro de "Lookup failed" ao usar um Glassfish Custom Resource

Tags: java, ejb, glassfish

Estou usando recurso de *Custom Resource do Glassfish* para gravar uma propriedade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí, estou tentando pegar este valor assim:

```
new InitialContext().lookup("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE")
```

mas recebo a seguinte `exception`:

```
Grave: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup resource : javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: value cannot be null]]]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.consisa.consisanet.core.application.ApplicationStage.getApplicationStage(ApplicationStage.java:26)
at com.consisa.consisanet.core.update.UpdateSchemasDB.init(UpdateSchemasDB.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:3993)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1199)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$000(EJBTimerService.java:89)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:1919)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup resource : javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: value cannot be null]]
at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy.throwResourceNotFoundException(ResourceProxy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy.create(ResourceProxy.java:89)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:480)
... 43 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: value cannot be null]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:513)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.naming.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:236)
at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy.create(ResourceProxy.java:87)
... 44 more
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas propriedades do objeto remova a propriedade `stage` e insira uma propriedade `value`. (A única propriedade para tipos simples).

Dentro do tópico, a convenção para nomes jndi é um pouco diferente da convenção de nomes para pacotes, por default usamos `/` ao invés de pontos `.`:

Criação do recurso:

```
asadmin create-custom-resource --restype=java.lang.String --factoryclass=org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory --property value="Development" javax/faces/stage
```

E do lado cliente:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
String stage = (String) ic.lookup("javax/faces/stage");
```

Ou ainda (dentro do seu EJB):

```
@Resource(lookup="javax/faces/stage")
private String stage;
```

---

**Fontes**:

[1] http://javahowto.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/how-to-create-simple-string-and.html

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482845/how-to-configure-glassfish-to-inject-string-in-ejb3-1

Comment: certinho, estava testando aqui e o nome do custom resource ficou "javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", ponto ou barra aqui não influencia mas o nome da property sim que tem que ser value mesmo como você comentou, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda

Comment: Olá @Cristian, sobre `.` vs `/`, não é questão de funcionar, é mais uma questão de convenção mesmo. Como o JNDI é uma interface para diversos *back-ends* (LDAP, Corba, RMI, DNS, Sistemas de arquivo, etc) é extremamente recomendável seguir uma nomenclatura sã. Seu nome remete a busca por EJBs em sistemas legados / pré [sintaxe portável](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html)). O nome com `/` usa convenção de árvores e sistemas de arquivo. Na verdade seria recomendável até usar `resoure/javax/faces/stage` para deixar claro que esse é um recurso.

Comment: Ok Anthony entendi